# Android nfcee_access.xml

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to run [android-se-access](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-se-access) which requires Secure element access and I have to include the certificate into nfcee_access.xml

I run the command

```
keytool -exportcert -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android|xxd -p -|tr -d '\n'
```

and include them into the file.
But installing the apk from eclipse onto google nexus 7 still results in a forced close.

Did I generate the cert incorrectly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check logcat output, if it says something like 'denied access to package xxx', there might be a problem. If you specified the `<pacakge/>` tag, make sure it's correct. You also need to restart the device after you modify `nfcee_access.xml`.

BTW, I haven't tried this on N7 (maybe I should), but it should work.

Comment: Thanks !! turn out i add the jar file incorrectly , I din read the full log and keep thinking i add the incorrect cert.
your blog is awesome, I learn about NFC from it

Comment: @Nikolay Elenkon: Is it possible to use NFCEE to talk to the SIM (and not the embedded SE)?

Comment: Technically, yes. If the device has SWP and drivers support switching between the two (or default to SIM). Presumably that's how Isis works.

Comment: Can my application change it on non-rooted devices?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to know if your signature is correct, is adding `<debug />` tag at the same level with signatures, and you will get an hex dump of the denied application's signature in logcat, so the only thing you have to do is copy and paste it in the `nfcee_access.xml` file.

Comment: Yes, but that will dump *all* other apps' certificates and is simply ridiculously noisy.